# Find Disabled Textbox control and save its value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the value of disabled textbox control.

First I am finding the textbox

```
TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)(Page.FindControl("txt1"))
```

Then saving the value of the textbox

```
decimal val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txt1.Text.Trim().ToString())
```

But I am not getting any value because it is not able to find the control because my Textbox control is disabled.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can directly get the value of text by using 
`string val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txt1.Text.Trim());`

Comment: how you set value to disabled texbox?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the textbox in  txt1?

Comment: My textbox is runat="server" and is not nested under any control. I need to find control since there are 9 textbox txt1, txt2..txt9. Using for loop I am saving the value. But I am not able to find control since textboxes are disabled

Comment: @rahulaggarwal what you mean _it is not able to find the control because my Textbox control is disabled_? your `(TextBox)(Page.FindControl("txt1"))` return `null`? or `txt1.Text` is empty string?

Comment: @rahulaggarwal can you provide your asp markup too?

Comment: @rahulaggarwal If you look at my answer, you may be better off using a `HiddenField` rather than a disabled textbox, as the control will push and pull value based on page construction / postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TextBox** might be nested inside other control. If so, you want to find it recursively.

For example,

### Helper Method

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
   if (root.ID == id) 
     return root;

   return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
      .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
      .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
}
```

### Usage

```
var txt1 =  (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(Page, "txt1");
```

Comment: My Textbox is on page, it is not inside any control

Answer (score 0):

A few more details would be helpful.  It should be as simple as:

```
string val1 = txt1.text;
```

You shouldn't even need to use FindControl unless there is a specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure  you are getting the textbox in txt1

also

```
  string val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txt1.Text.Trim().ToString())
```

Your code is wrong.. how can you convert a decimal into a string

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a numeric value in your textbox, so try doing it like this:

```
decimal value = 0;
string money = String.Empty;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMoney.Text))
     name = txtMoney.Text

value = Convert.ToDecimal(name);
```

That will validate your textbox to avoid a null, but will also convert it into a decimal value for it.  Hope it helps.

You shouldn't need to `FindControl` before you can assign the value, you should be able to pass values in <strike>and out</strike>, as long as your markup has `runat="server"`.  <strike>The server side postback will provide access to the inner content of the control without a problem.</strike>

**After testing, a disabled control won't push the value during a postback. You really should use the `HiddenField`.**

However, a `<asp:HiddenField>` may be better suited to your requirements.  Rather than a disabled textbox.  Which would like like this:

```
string cash = String.Empty;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfMoney.Value))
     cash = hfMoney.Value;
```

The hidden field will always be hidden, thus it is always accessible.

Comment: server side control already use hidden field, so if value set in server side - all work, but if value set on client - then you right, this value won't push to server